# Module not found error no module named 'app' Heroku :

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I deployed my Flask App on Heroku numerous time. Even after successful builds my app is not running. It keep on saying some Application Error whenever I open my link.

1. main.py

   ```
   from flask import Flask, render_template, request,session,redirect
   from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
   from flask_mail import Mail
   import json
   from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
   from datetime import datetime
   import os
   import math

   with open('config.json', 'r') as c:
       params = json.load(c)["params"]

   local_server = True
   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.secret_key = 'key'
   app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']=params['upload_location']
   #app.secret_key = 'super-secret-key'
   app.config.update(                       #for mail updates
       MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
       MAIL_PORT = '465',
       MAIL_USE_SSL = True,
       MAIL_USERNAME = params['gmail-user'],
       MAIL_PASSWORD = params['gmail-password']
   )
   mail = Mail(app)
   if (local_server):
       app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['local_uri']
   else:
       app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['prod_uri']

   db = SQLAlchemy(app)


   class Contacts(db.Model):
       sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
       phone_num = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
       msg = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
       date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
       email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

   class Posts(db.Model):
       sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
       slug = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
       content = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
       date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
       tagline = db.Column(db.String(20) , nullable = False)
       img_file = db.Column(db.String(12) , nullable = True)

   @app.route("/")
   def home():
       posts = Posts.query.filter_by().all()
       last = math.ceil(len(posts)/int(params['no_of_posts']))
       page = request.args.get('page')
       if(not str(page).isnumeric()):
           page = 1

       page= int(page)
       posts = posts[(page-1)*int(params['no_of_posts']):(page-1)*int(params['no_of_posts']) + int(params['no_of_posts'])]
       #Pagination Logic
       #when user is on first page
       if(page==1):
           prev="#"
           next = "/?page="+str(page+1)
       #when user is on last page
       elif(page==last):
           prev = "/?page=" + str(page-1)
           next = "#"
       else:
           prev = "/?page=" + str(page - 1)
           next = "/?page=" + str(page + 1)

       #posts = Posts.query.filter_by().all()[0:params['no_of_posts']]
       return render_template('index.html', params = params , posts =posts , prev = prev , next = next )

   @app.route("/post/<string:post_slug>",methods = ['GET'])
   def post_route(post_slug):
       post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug = post_slug).first()
       return render_template('post.html',params=params, post=post)



   @app.route("/about")
   def about():
       return render_template('about.html', params=params)

   @app.route("/logout")
   def logout():
       session.pop('user')
       return redirect('/dashboard')

   @app.route("/contact", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def contact():
       if (request.method == 'POST'):
           name = request.form.get('name')
           email = request.form.get('email')
           phone = request.form.get('phone')
           message = request.form.get('message')
           entry = Contacts(name=name, phone_num=phone, msg=message, date=datetime.now(), email=email)
           db.session.add(entry)
           db.session.commit()
           mail.send_message('New message from blog',
                             sender = email,
                             recipients = [params['gmail-user']],
                             body = message + "\n" + phone
                             )
       return render_template('contact.html', params=params)


   @app.route("/dashboard" , methods = ['GET','POST'])
   def dashboard():
       if 'user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user'] :
           posts = Posts.query.all()
           return render_template('dashboard.html',posts = posts)
       #check if the admin is already logged in


       if request.method=='POST':
           username = request.form.get('uname')
           userpass = request.form.get('pass')
           if(username == params['admin_user'] and userpass == params['admin_password']):
               #set the session variable
               session['user'] = username
               posts = Posts.query.all()
               return render_template('dashboard.html',params = params ,posts= posts)

           #REDIRECT TO ADMIN PANEL
           else:
              return render_template('login.html', params=params)

   @app.route("/delete/<string:sno>" , methods = ['GET','POST'])
   def delete(sno):
       if 'user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']:
           post = Posts.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
           db.session.delete(post)
           db.session.commit()
       return redirect('/dashboard')


   @app.route("/uploader", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def uploader():
       if ("user" in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']):
           if(request.method == 'POST'):
               f = request.files['file1']
               f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],secure_filename(f.filename)))
               return "Uploaded successfully"


   @app.route("/edit/<string:sno>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def edit(sno):
       if ("user" in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']):
           if request.method == "POST":
               box_title = request.form.get('title')
               tline = request.form.get('tagline')
               slug = request.form.get('slug')
               content = request.form.get('content')
               img_file = request.form.get('img_file')
               date = datetime.now()

               if sno == '0':
                   post = Posts(title=box_title, slug=slug, content=content, tagline=tline, img_file=img_file, date=date)
                   db.session.add(post)
                   db.session.commit()
               else:
                   post=Posts.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
                   post.title = box_title
                   post.slug  = slug
                   post.content = content
                   post.tagline = tline
                   post.img_file = img_file
                   post.date = date
                   db.session.commit()
                   return redirect('/edit/'+sno)

           post = Posts.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
           return render_template('edit.html', params = params,post = post,sno=sno )

   app.run(debug=True)
   ```
2. Build Logs

   ```
   021-04-22T10:06:26.320935+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.320999+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:06:26 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344420+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344423+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344617+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 551, in manage_workers
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344765+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 623, in spawn_workers
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344907+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344910+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344999+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.344999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345124+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345165+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345173+00:00 app[web.1]:
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345173+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345173+00:00 app[web.1]:
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345176+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345179+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345221+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345228+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345283+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345285+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345370+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345387+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345437+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345449+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345528+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345635+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345637+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345782+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345786+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345855+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345976+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.345992+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.401569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
   2021-04-22T10:06:26.494132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
   2021-04-22T10:52:27.200311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
   2021-04-22T10:52:32.303098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:main`
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.765500+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.765624+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:26129 (4)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.765700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.775598+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.775902+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779141+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779149+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779150+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779150+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779151+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779151+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779152+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779152+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779152+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779153+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779153+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779153+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779154+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779154+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779154+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779156+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.779236+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782185+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782186+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782189+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782189+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782189+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782190+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782190+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782190+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782191+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782191+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782192+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782192+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782192+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782193+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782193+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782194+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782194+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782194+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.782196+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.786188+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.831703+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.927217+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
   2021-04-22T10:52:35.927266+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 10:52:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
   2021-04-22T10:52:36.443389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
   2021-04-22T10:52:36.637578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
   2021-04-22T10:55:27.910059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cs-sansar.herokuapp.com request_id=af486d95-d3bc-463a-8181-3c88c66df999 fwd="59.97.255.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
   2021-04-22T11:05:08.286594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cs-sansar.herokuapp.com request_id=051b33c9-4d95-4382-b49a-06b86b285692 fwd="59.97.255.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
   2021-04-22T11:11:29.478766+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cs-sansar.herokuapp.com request_id=c6819801-a01f-4ad4-8650-f252e4898a3b fwd="59.97.255.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
   ```
3. Config.json

   ```
   {
        "params":
        {
          "local_server": "True",
          "local_uri": "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost/cs-sansar",
          "prod_uri": "mysql+mysqlconnector://",
          "blog_name": "cs-sansar",
          "tag-line" : "Heaven for programmers",
          "gmail-user": "abc16@gmail.com",
          "gmail-password": "vxnv2",
          "about_text": "CS-SANSAR or the computer science world is the absolute and right place for the geeks who want to learn trending technologies. We at CS-SANSAR  provide you with efficient roadmaps to master any new tech.",
          "about_dev_text": "Hi everyone ! This is Vinayak . I like to blog with a deep passion for learning and tutoring latest technology.",
          "no_of_posts": 2,
          "login_image": "login.jpg",
          "admin_user" : "admin_user",
          "admin_password": "admin@123",
          "upload_location": "C:\\Users\\asus\\PycharmProjects\\Flask-blog\\static\\img"

        }
      }
   ```

Also how to correctly set production URL in config.json?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python - this may help, you might be doing something fundamentally wrong

Comment: How does your `Procfile` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't include **Procfile** .
write this in terminal

```
pip install gunicorn
```

go to requirements.txt and add gunicorn==(version of gunicorn)

then make a Procfile(P should be capital) in root folder and add this

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

push it to heroku git